# how to traverse the given list and find average of second index of tuples and store in a new list in python

Tags: python, list, average

I know this is a silly question but I'm new in python and don't know how to do it. Actually I have retrieved some data from mysql database and got that as following list.

```
[
    (7, 80),
    (7, 40),
    (7, 100),
    (34, 100),
    (34, 20),
    (36, 60),
    (36, 40),
    (36, 100),
    (36, 60),
]
```

The name of list is "norm_rating". in every tuple like (7,80) the first element is "id" and second element is normalized value of "rating". What I want is to get a new list in which I will have 1 unique entry of every "id" and average of rating from the "norm_rating" list. Like I want new list to be,

```
[(7, 73.3), (34, 60), (36, 65)]
```

can I please have a python code for this.

Comment: Checkout `defaultdict`

Comment: "I spent a full day on it but not able to do it" Show us what you wrote, and explain what went wrong when you tried to use it.

Comment: I'm not getting required ouput. just trying it with loops and if else statements but getting messy results that are not as per required.

Comment: Regardless show us where you are right now. Use cases differ. Just "wanting python code for this" is going to result in a lot of confused and potentially unhelpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `itertools.groupby` to group the tuples with the same first element, and then just use `statistics.mean` to get the average of the second elements:

```
>>> data = [(7, 80), (7, 40), (7, 100), (34, 100), (34, 20), (36, 60), (36, 40), (36, 100), (36, 60)]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> [(n, mean(t[1] for t in group)) for n, group in groupby(data, lambda t: t[0])]
[(7, 73.33333333333333), (34, 60), (36, 65)]
```

Comment: hi sir! It definitely worked for me. Thank you so much. Can you please give me your contact as I have some more queries and stackoverflow allows only 2 question that I have done already. I will be really thankful.